# How to create click-able link in MobaXterm

Tags: url, hyperlink, port, mobaxterm

I would like to create an url link that can be CTRL-Click-ed in MobaXterm and opens the link in the default local the browser.

A simple web address (like http://example.com) is recognized by MobaXterm and you can click on it. However i need to add a port, which is not recognitzed. http://example.com:8888 only recognized till the colon.

However I saw on the MobaXterms initial screen other clickable links.
For more info, ctrl+click on help or visit our website
[image: See link in header]

I tried to add clickable links like described below but it does not work with MobaXterm
https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda